Errors with Dynamic Routing in Next.js. trying to fetch and display individual details based on slug
I'm trying to get the individual slug for each job that I have posted. I am using the app router and have set up the following page: src/app/Job/[slug]/page.js
Here's the code:
async function getJobById(slug) {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/Job/${slug}`, {
    method: "GET",
  });

  return response.json();
}

export default async function JobId({ params }) {
  const { slug } = await getJobById(params.slug);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{slug.pay}</h1>
      <h1>{slug.aboutCompany}</h1>
      <h1>{slug.experience}</h1>
etc...
    </>
  );
}


I have several jobs posted, but when I attempt to click on one using this link located in the jobsCard.js component <Link href={/Job/${slug}}>View job</Link>, I encounter numerous errors. Trying different solutions.
edit adding my api/route.js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of req.body) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    const body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(
      "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.eikbxrn.mongodb.net/jobupload?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0"
    );
    const db = client.db();

    const propertyCollections = db.collection("jobs");

    const result = await propertyCollections.insertOne(data);

    console.log(result);

    client.close();

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "job uploaded" });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Failed to upload job" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

export async function GET(request) {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.eikbxrn.mongodb.net/jobupload?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0"
  );
  const db = client.db();

  const propertyCollections = db.collection("jobs");

  const result = await propertyCollections.find().toArray();

  client.close();

  return NextResponse.json(result);
}


export default async function JobId({ params }) {
  const { slug } = await getJobById(params.id);
}

You are passing params.id to getJobById() but you set your dynamic route to use [slug] in your case you should use params.slug, check the example provided in nextjs docs.
If you wanna use id you can change your folder name to job/[id]/page.js
or even [jobId] and make sure you are using the correct name in your params (params.jobId or params.id depending on your folder name)
EDIT: after further reading your post I noticed you using Next Link as follows <Link href={/Job/${slug}}>View job</Link> in your JobCard component but you are not passing the id

thanks! im still getting the same errors however, might be due to my api. I have my src/app/api/route.js which contains my mongodb db im sending a GET req so do i need to change this line ?   const response = await fetch(http://localhost:3000/api/Job/${slug}, {

Hi, you can share your API route handler code and folder structure, so i can examine it

And if there are any errors, can i see the error message too ?

@EvanGordon no you do not have to change slug in your getJobById since you are passing it as a property, You can try to console before calling fetch to make sure that you are passing the correct id to your function.
Please share all the errors you encountering so we can tackle them one by one also I edit the post

getting this error now Error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Source
src/app/Job/[slug]/page.js (7:10) @ async getJobById
5 |
6 |   console.log("this is response", response);

7 |   return await response.json();

Appreciate your help

@EvanGordon did you pass id to JobsCard as suggested

now with this error Error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Source
src/app/Job/[slug]/page.js (10:20) @ async JobId
8 |
9 | export default async function JobId({ params }) {

10 |   const { slug } = await getJobById(params.slug);
|                    ^
11 |
12 |   return (


yes in jobsCard.js <Link href={/Job/${slug}}> View job </Link> then in jobs.js I have
{jobmaps.map((job) => (
        <JobsCard
          key={job.id}
          companyName={job.companyName}
          country={job.country}
          setting={job.setting}
          role={job.jobTitle}
          elevatorPitch={job.aboutCompany}
          experience={job.experience}
          pay={job.pay}
          slug={job.slug}
        />
      ))}


@EvanGordon I see you passing a property called slug = {job.slug} to your JobsCard
you are not passing the id to your component the line key={job.id} is to make sure each item in your list is unique, to make sure you are passing your id to the child component replace slug={job.slug} by slug={job.id}.
I recommend renaming your variables/properties to something more expressive you are confusing URL params by your data attributes.

I think that if your folder structure is src/app/Job/[slug]/page.js then you have to access the slug.
So your code should have been:
export default async function JobId({ params }) {
  const { slug } = await getJobById(params.slug);


thanks i fixed that bug yeah but still encountering the errors. i think its due to my api im fetching
